# How to determine if View is partially visible

Tags: android

I have a layout with an EditView and a couple of Buttons below it. When the keyboard is displayed, the lower Button, depending on the height of the screen, may become partially or fully hidden. Depending on what the user typed, I want to make sure that the lower button is fully visible. For now, I simply hide the keyboard, but on a larger screen, I would much rather leave the keyboard on the screen, if the lower button is fully visible.

button.getVisibility() return VISIBLE, even if the button is only partially visible.

How can I detect the partial visibility condition?

Comment: just FYI, visibility has nothing to do with view being overlapped by other views

Answer (score 0):

The visibility of a widget only depends on itself and not its siblings or any other view in the hierarchy so other can getting co ordinates of views and dimensions and performing computations there's no other way.

However in your case you can use [android:windowSoftInputMode](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) to adjust your layout when the keyboard is shown

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode does not solve my problem. The only two applicable options are adjustPan and adjustResize, but both kick in when the EditView (the view that has the focus) is not fully visible. In my case, it's the button below, that doesn't really have a focus, that becomes partially/fully hidden.